# Strongest way to do nominal types in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, newtype, nominal-typing, opaque-types

I've seen many different ways to do nominal types in Typescript, but they all seem to fall short in some way. I'd like all these properties to hold:

1. Must have clear (not necessarily concise, but bonus points if so) compiler error messages communicating *which* opaque types, e.g. `Type 'GBP' is not assignable to type 'JPY'`.
2. Must be truly unique to avoid accidentally matching similar opaque types, i.e. no `__tag__` keys, must use `unique symbol`.
3. Must be able to have safe generic functions taking opaque types sharing the same underlying primitive type, e.g. `<A>(Opaque<number, A>) => Opaque<number, A>`.

More bonus points for a syntactically clean interface, but I understand that's subjective.

Answer (score 6):

This is the best approach I've discovered:

```
namespace Unique {
  export declare const Newtype: unique symbol
  export declare const JPY: unique symbol
  export declare const GBP: unique symbol
}

type Newtype<A, B extends symbol> = A & { readonly [Unique.Newtype]: B }

type JPY = Newtype<number, typeof Unique.JPY>
type GBP = Newtype<number, typeof Unique.GBP>

const test: <A extends symbol>(a: Newtype<number, A>, b: Newtype<number, A>) => Newtype<number, A>
  = (a, b) => a + b as any // massage the type checker a bit

// fails
test(10 as GBP, 10)
test(10 as GBP, 10 as JPY)

// passes
test(10 as GBP, 10 as GBP)
test(10 as JPY, 10 as JPY)
```

1. holds, but no bonus points here because you end up with some really nasty error messages containing file paths ([live example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AYwDYEMrDsiA7AZ3gDlgB3GATzGAC44BXPASwEcHsDKBbAIwlQAoUJFiIUGLDnxE4AKQAKATXpM2HOFz4Dh4aPCRpM2XIXgBxAEILVLdpx78hgqjTikK1YAB4AggBo4SzhQGGA8BAJNRwEAPjgAXjhfOAAyOABvOCx0BHxUSjgAbQ9XYABdemCAX0EXL3llRPdyMu88Bj5gKECyiAAzRqVY+rcrBWbSr3bO3m7erwG4cZHBU1kwono-EJAwiKitJ1iACnR6KZoZrp7k2MDeC9bpjpvA31iASkT4y59Xua3D6CODNM4Pb4JeLoOAAajgvDg6Ci6DwlDqAHoMXB+uhmKgCC5gEQTgBGAAMSKi40CFM+RJJFKpy2stMpyKG9MEWLgYGRBGJDJgZPZ1NZcCZHPG9M2wslUUUSjZzMVnyAA), see "Errors"): `Newtype<number, typeof import("file:///input").JPY>`. I'm hoping there's a way involving [interface extends](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34777#issuecomment-551993933) or similar to make this cleaner.
2. holds because both `Unique.Newtype` and `Unique.JPY` are `unique symbol`s.
3. holds because we can use the structure of `Newtype` to ensure the types are definitely `Newtype`, due to the fact that it's defined in terms of `Unique.Newtype` which is `unique symbol`.